# Encountering a PHP error "Illegal string offset" in fetching data using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

So, I am experimenting on a web app. What I want to do is displaying a user's list of posts in the timeline by matching the logged-in user's id with the id on the 'posts' database.

here's my model

```
public function load_posts($user_id)
{
    $this->db->where("user_id",$user_id);
    $query=$this->db->get('posts');

    if ($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            $haha = array(
                'post_id'   => $rows->id,
                'title'     => $rows->title,
                'artist'    => $rows->artist,
                'album'     => $rows->album,
                'caption'   => $rows->caption,
            );
        }   
        return $haha;
    }
    return array();
}
```

my controller

```
public function welcome()
{
    $data['title']= 'Welcome';

    $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $haha['hah'] = $this->user_model->load_posts($user_id);

    $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
    $this->load->view('welcome_view.php', $haha);
    $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
}
```

and the view

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="boxes">
        <table>
        <?php
            foreach($hah as $rows):
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['artist']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['album']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['caption']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

With those codes, I get 4 rows of these errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'title'

Filename: views/welcome_view.php

Line Number: 25

2   
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'artist'

Filename: views/welcome_view.php

Line Number: 26

2   
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'album'

Filename: views/welcome_view.php

Line Number: 27

2   
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'caption'

Filename: views/welcome_view.php

Line Number: 28

2
```

and just in case its needed, my 'posts' table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`artist` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`album` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cover` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`caption` text NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`postTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you put the database "where" above the get function, within your model?

Comment: You've attached `$haha` to your view, and try to loop on `$hah` `foreach($hah as $rows):`. Isn't it a typo? I do not see `$hah` anywhere.

Comment: `$haha` v.s. `$hah`?

Comment: You can actually found the hah in $haha['hah'] = $this->user_model->load_posts($user_id); (in the controller. I was just playing around with the variable names.

Comment: @Craig: oh yea I swapped em just to try to see whether it's affectiong anything and turns out it's not and i forgot to return it to its original positions before posting it here. Restored it back to it's original state

Answer (score 0):

Your returned array of results is not using the keys as you expect them to appear, yet you are trying to access them.  The best way to get familiar with the return structures in Codeigniter is to read the documentation OR if you're a more 'hands-dirty' type like myself, just put a `var_dump($haha)` in your model right before the return statement.

Comment: I'm a newbie in using CI, so I guess yeah I'm not familiar with the return structures yet

Comment: Thats great! You will learn a lot, at first glance it appears you're returning an array of arrays with keys. Here's the link to CI's database return results. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the profiler turned on? Do you see the right query being generated?

You need to flip around what you have.

```
$this->db->where("user_id", $user_id);
$query = $this->db->get('posts');
```

or you can use `get_where`

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

Comment: In your controller put `var_dump($haha['hah']);` ... what does that display?

Comment: it displayed 'array(5) { ["post_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["title"]=> string(20) "Far Side of the Moon" ["artist"]=> string(7) "Tinashe" ["album"]=> string(8) "Aquarius" ["caption"]=> string(6) "A6 bgt" }' on top of the page

Comment: `$this->load->view('welcome_view.php', $haha);` ... what if you remove the `.php` extension from the view and just have `$this->load->view('welcome_view', $haha);`

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. But the data is coming back because you can see that with the `var_dump()` ... you're passing that to the view so you should be able to access it via `$hah`.